Is there any tools for doing load-test for centrifuge based websocket?
I got a task to do a web-socket client loadtest. The problem is, if the web-socket server is using native web-socket it can use locust, but because this is centrifuge web-socket i'm unable to find the tools for doing this task. The centrifuge client can be found here https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifuge-python
I've tried to build own load-test mechanism similar with locust, but i feel like it doesn't meets the load-test requirement and not same as locust execution(esp with cpu, memory, and multi processing and threading)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
